# http request forking

Tags: http, reverse-proxy, staging

I have an http server running my webservice and a staging server, running my latest builds. I'd like to performance test my staging environment, by "*copying*" all requests, and forward them to my test servers and the productive one. The responses given by the testserver should be discarded, the other should be delivered to the server.

My first approach was, to search a http proxy, that offers this kind of functionality. But I only found [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). Which leaks memory, as I discovered in a test run.

Are there any other solutions? Or at least is there a more stable http proxy for this work?

Thanks,

mkkl